# Below average, average, and above average - miles driven per year

Tags: statistics, average

Assume a vehicle is driven, on average, 12,000 miles per year. What would be considered:

- Way below average?
- Below average?
- Above average?
- Way above average?

Is there some sort of formula that could be applied to determine this? For example, can we give "average" a tolerance of +-10%? Anything outside of that +-10% would be below or above average?

Or would this be represented in a standard bell curve? So average would be +- ~34%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below and above are just less and more than $12,000$ miles/year.  Way below and way above are not mathematical terms.  I would suggest the bottom and top $10\%$ of the population, but one could argue for other numbers.  In any case, you need to know something about the distribution besides the mean to be able to answer.  If $90\%$ of the people drive between $11,900$ and $12,100$ you could consider way below to be anything less than $11,900$

Comment: What if I had, say, data from 1,000 vehicles from various years and all with their own mileage? And let's say that the mean of _my sample_ isn't actually 12,000 miles/year. Could I still build a distribution wherein 12,000 was the mean (let's say that I'm confident that the government's estimate of 12,000 miles per year is accurate -- and it's just that my sample is too small to also get the same mean)? If so, how?

Comment: If you don't know how your sample was selected you can't say much about all the cars.  Maybe you got a sample of people who use the pay by mile insurance.  That will be biased low, but how much?  You could certainly look at the distribution you got and see if you are reasonably close to 12000.